# scanf skipped after reading in integer in C, in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I have a section of code where I check the input to scanf is valid. i.e. if scanf returns a non zero positive number. This is part of my code:

```
while(scanf(" %d",&choice)<=0){
        printf("Incorrect value entered, please re-enter\n");
    }
```

Where “choice” is an integer.

Every time I run this code, the compiler skips past the scanf after the while loops is executed. I get an output like this:

---

Welcome to the Predator/Prey Calculator

Please enter your name

Dan
Hi Dan

Please choose one of the following options:
    1. Calculate the evolution of a TYPICAL predator and prey system
    2. Calculate the evolution of a SPECIFIC predator and prey system
    3. Calculate the evolution of a CUSTOM predator and prey system
    0. Quit
a
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter

### Incorrect value entered, please re-enter

Could you explain why this happens! I can’t seem to find any answers on the internet specific to reading in integers.

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you expecting that the input should be `> 0` ? Like 1,15,100 ?

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of fields successfully converted: please read the man page.

Comment: Yes, input should be more than zero. I am using the int return value from scanf, which should be equal to the number of values read in, or <=0 for a failed attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** First complaint is that `scanf()` returns the number of fields successfully converted. The next problem is that `scanf` leaves unconverted characters in the input, and will try to convert these same characters again. After a duff input, you can clear the input like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCHOICE 42

int main(void)
{
    int choice, ch;
    while(scanf("%d",&choice) != 1 || choice < 1 || choice > MAXCHOICE){
        printf("Incorrect value entered, please re-enter\n");
        while((ch = getchar(stdin)) != '\n');     // clear the input
    }
    printf("Choice %d\n", choice);
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
100
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
a
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter
5
Choice 5
```

Comment: Still having the same issue, scanf skips on each run of the while loop

Comment: @Dan revised my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that in case the user does not input a number your program will loop forever. This is because `scanf` will repeatedly try to parse the same string and keep failing.
What you have to do is to match whatever the user has written and then ask again for a number:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int choice;
    while(scanf("%d",&choice) <= 0){
        scanf("%*s"); // this will parse anything the user has written
        printf("Incorrect value entered, please re-enter\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The * in the scanf format string is the assignment suppression character, from scanf man page:

> '*' assignment-suppression character: scanf() reads input
>   as directed by the conversion specification,  but  discards
>                 the  input.   No  corresponding  pointer  argument is required, and this specification is not included in the count of
>   successful
>                 assignments returned by scanf().

Comment: When `stdin` closes and `scanf()` return `EOF`, proposed answer is an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried sending C-d and it ask again for input. How would stdin close otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int choice,repeat = 0;

    do{
        printf("Give a Number: ");
        if((scanf("%d",&choice)) != 1){
            printf("ErrorFix it!\n");
            exit(1);
        }else{
            if(choice > 0){
                printf("OK\n");
                repeat = 0;
            }else{
                printf("Incorrect value entered, please re-enter\n");
                repeat = 1;
            }
        }
    }while(repeat == 1);

    printf("Your typed %d\n",choice);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Give a Number: 0
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter

Give a Number: -5
Incorrect value entered, please re-enter

Give a Number: 10
OK
Your typed 10
```